# Jade/pug - link wrapping behind last tag in the same container

Tags: pug

I just have a tiny question I can't find the answer to regarding jade/pug template engine, and that is the behavior of link tags. I'm just dipping my toes into this templating engine and so far it looks cool.

Why does this:

```
#container.col
  a link
  if youAreUsingJade
    p You are amazing
  else
    p Get on it!
  a link
  p.
    Jade is a terse and simple
    templating language with a
    strong focus on performance
    and powerful features.
  a link
```

Compile into this?:

```
<div id="container" class="col"><a>link</a>
  <p>You are amazing</p><a>link</a>
  <p>
    Jade is a terse and simple
    templating language with a
    strong focus on performance
    and powerful features.
  </p><a>link</a>
</div>
```

They are in the same container, so why does the link tag wrap around to the last tag?

I would kind of expect it to look like this:

```
<div id="container" class="col">
  <a>link</a>
  <p>You are amazing</p>
  <a>link</a>
  <p>
    Jade is a terse and simple
    templating language with a
    strong focus on performance
    and powerful features.
  </p>
  <a>link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pug compiler does not add new lines for inline elements including `<a>` tags even if the `pretty` option is used.

> [Inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) are those between which new lines carry a meaning and cannot be used for cosmetic purposes. For example `<span>` is an inline element since `</span><span>` and `</span>\n<span>` are different, so we don't insert new lines. For block level elements like `<div>` we can safely insert new lines for indentation purposes.
>
> https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2075#issuecomment-138125136

You could force the result you said you were expecting by using something like `= "\n\t"` before each `a link` but that gets messy and unmanageable.

Also from the same issue comment referenced above:

> I feel that we need to clarify that in general pretty-printing is not encouraged.

I find that the developer tools of modern browsers output the html quite well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="potato.jpg"></a>` wrapping around `<img src="potato.jpg">` it's because your image is indented like so

```
a(href='https://www.facebook.com/')
 img(src='potato.jpg')
```

The solution would be simple

```
a(href='https://www.facebook.com/')
img(src='potato.jpg')
```

Jade is very specific with the indentation and if an element is indented it is considered a child element. All the children have to have the same indentation

Comment: I should have specified that I meant the <p> tag. Since it is not straight under the paragraph in the html which I would expect, but rather behind the closing paragraph tag.